# Iterate a function until result from called function is equal, javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to iterate a function several times until it returns same thing twice.

This needs to go into a for-loop somehow but I can't get my head around how to this. Here's some code with 4 manual iterations. Any ideas how to put this in a for-loop?

```
Velocity.prototype.removeCombinedDistancesThatAreShorterThanTrainLength = function(wayPoints, lengthOfTrain){
  var firstTry = this.removeWayPointsWhichAreShorterThenTrainLength(wayPoints, lengthOfTrain);
  var secondTry = this.removeWayPointsWhichAreShorterThenTrainLength(firstTry, lengthOfTrain);

  if(firstTry === secondTry){
    return firstTry;
  }else{
    var thirdTry = this.removeWayPointsWhichAreShorterThenTrainLength(secondTry, lengthOfTrain);
    if(thirdTry === secondTry){
      return secondTry
    }else{
      var forthTry = this.removeWayPointsWhichAreShorterThenTrainLength(thirdTry, lengthOfTrain);
      if(thirdTry === forthTry){
        return forthTry
      }
    }
  }
  return forthTry;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (not tried, but should give you the general idea):

```
var lastTry = null;    
var thisTry = wayPoints;
do 
{
    lastTry = thisTry;
    thisTry = this.removeWayPointsWhichAreShorterThenTrainLength(lastTry, lengthOfTrain);
} while (lastTry !== thisTry);
```

If it's possible that the result will never become equal, consider implementing a safeguard for this, like a maximum number of iterations.